# Fourier transform and convolution product

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, convolution, harmonic-analysis

Find the Fourier transform of the function:

$$ I(x) = \int^{1/2}_{0} e^{-(x-t)^2} dt$$
using the theorem about convolution products.

The theorem states that $\mathcal{F} \{f *g\} = \mathcal{F} \{f\} \mathcal{F}\{ g \}$.

I am given the following hint:

Write $I(x)=f*g(x)$, where $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ and $g(x)=\chi_{[0, 1/2]}$.

Then using the convolution rule you get:

$$\mathcal{F}\{I\}(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} e^{-t^2/4} \times \frac{i (1-e^{i t/2})}{\sqrt{2 \pi} t}.$$

But I am stuck here. The same question, but it does not provide a detailed solution: [Fourier transform using convolution product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3501625/fourier-transform-using-convolution-product)

A detailed answer would help me a lot, as I do not have neither notes nor examples explaining this.

Thanks.

Comment: that is the Fourier transform, you've already found it

Comment: @fGDu94 I am given that as a hint. I did not get it. I have edited the question to clarify.

Comment: Ah I see, do you understand why $I(x) = f*g(x)$?

Comment: @fGDu94 not really...

Comment: $\int^{1/2}_{0} e^{-(x-t)^2}dt = \int_0^{\infty}\mathbb{1}_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]}e^{-(x-t)^2}dt = \int_0^{\infty} f(x-t)g(t)dt = f*g(x)$ with $f,g$ defined as above

Comment: @fGDu94 Thanks but I do not see why $\int_0^{\infty}\mathbb{1}_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]}e^{-(x-t)^2}dt = \int_0^{\infty} f(x-t)g(t)dt$. Why does $f(x-t)$ show up here? Sorry but I do not have notes explaining convolution related to Fourier Transforms...

Comment: because $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$ so $f(x-t) = e^{-(x-t)^2}$. The convolution $f*g(x)$ is defined as $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x-t)g(t)dt$

Comment: @fGDu94 Thank you, I see it know. If you were to post an answer explaining how to get the Fourier Transform I would be grateful.