# Fourier transform with convolution

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, convolution

> Find the Fourier transform of the following function: $$I(x) = \int_0^{1/2} e^{-(x-t)^2}dt$$

I tried using the convolution product, which is defined as: $$(f \ast g)(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dt' f(t') g(t-t')$$
So that I can use the property $\mathcal{F} \{ f \ast g \} = \mathcal{F} \{f \}\mathcal{F}\{g\}$. But it looks like I can't find the functions $f$ and $g$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related but not answered yet: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3518394/fourier-transform-and-convolution-product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse the order of integration
$$
\begin{split}
\mathcal{F}\{I\}(s)
 &= \int_{x=-\infty}^{x=\infty} \int_{t=0}^{t=1/2} \exp\left(-(x-t)^2-2\pi i s x\right)\ dt\ dx \\
 &= \int_{t=0}^{t=1/2} e^{-t^2}\int_{x=-\infty}^{x=\infty} \exp\left(-x^2-2x (t-i\pi s)\right)\ dx\ dt
\end{split}
$$
now complete the square in the exponent in the inner integral and you will get a term that will cancel out $e^{-t^2}$ leaving you with an $e^{-t}$ like integral to take wrt $t$.

Comment: Great! But any idea how I could involve the convolutionproduct?

Comment: @Kabouter9 no, sorry

Comment: this helped if you wanted an answer: [Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3518394/fourier-transform-and-convolution-product)

Comment: @Kabouter9 nice, thank you